# sql query for finding not included items

Tags: sql

Recently I had a test question which I failed to answer.
Now I just want to understand how to implement it.

Tables:

```
goods                               warehouse               product                     brand
--------                            -----------             ---------                   ----------
id (PK)                             id (PK)                 id (PK)                     id (PK)
warehouseId (FK -> warehouse.id)    name                    name                        name
productId (FK -> product.id)                                brandId (FK -> brand.id)    
quantity
```

Objective is to retrieve brand.name by warehouses with quantity in descending order and **brands that are not presented in the warehouse should be in result too**

It is relatively easy to reslove first part of the objective:

```
SELECT brand.name as brand_name, sum(goods.quantity) as qty, warehouse.name as warehouse_name from brand 
    JOIN product ON (brand.id = product.brandid)
    JOIN goods ON (product.id = goods.productid)
    JOIN warehouse ON (goods.warehouseid = warehouse.id)    
    GROUP BY brand_name, warehouse_name
    ORDER BY warehouse_name, qty desc 
;
```

result is:

```
 brand_name | qty |  warehouse_name  
------------+-----+------------------
 samsung    | 343 | First warehouse
 sony       | 200 | First warehouse
 toshiba    | 111 | First warehouse
 siemens    |  92 | First warehouse
 tesla      |  42 | First warehouse
 samsung    | 382 | Second warehouse
 sony       | 111 | Second warehouse
 toshiba    |  39 | Second warehouse
 toshiba    | 421 | Third warehouse
 samsung    | 172 | Third warehouse
 sony       |  23 | Third warehouse
 tesla      |  17 | Third warehouse
```

Qestion is how to include brands that are not presented by warehouses?

This is a proper result example:

```
 brand_name | qty |  warehouse_name  
------------+-----+------------------
 samsung    | 343 | First warehouse
 sony       | 200 | First warehouse
 toshiba    | 111 | First warehouse
 siemens    |  92 | First warehouse
 tesla      |  42 | First warehouse
 samsung    | 382 | Second warehouse
 sony       | 111 | Second warehouse
 toshiba    |  39 | Second warehouse
 siemens    |  0  | Second warehouse
 tesla      |  0  | Second warehouse
 toshiba    | 421 | Third warehouse
 samsung    | 172 | Third warehouse
 sony       |  23 | Third warehouse
 tesla      |  17 | Third warehouse
 siemens    |  0  | Third warehouse
```

Comment: left join(s) is what you want.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a combination of a CROSS JOIN and a LEFT JOIN.  A CROSS JOIN is where no explicit join between one table and the next thus causing every row in the first table to be joined with every in the second.  So, Joining every product to every warehouse will give you the master list of ALL possible combinations.  Then, you can LEFT-JOIN to the goods table of ACTUAL products available.

Start with the master list of ALL things and LEFT JOIN to the others.  Then you keep where there is nothing (via NULL) in the other.

```
select
      AllPossible.ProductID,
      p.name ProductName,
      AllPossible.warehouseID,
      w.name WarehouseName,
      p.brandID,
      b.name BrandName
   from
      ( select
              p1.id productID,
              w1.id warehouseID
           from
              product p1
                 cross join warehouse w1 ) AllPossible
         LEFT JOIN goods g
            on AllPossible.productID = g.productID
           AND AllPossible.warehouseID = g.warehouseID
         -- Now, re-join for product, warehouse and brand so we can get
         -- the details of where it is NOT found...
         -- I can get the descriptions from these three base on the"AllPossible"
         JOIN product p
            on AllPossible.productID = p.id
            JOIN brand b
               on p.brandid = b.id
         JOIN warehouse w
            on AllPossible.warehouseID = w.id
   where
      -- and only get records where it is NOT found in the goods table via NULL
      g.id IS NULL
```